# how to filter pandas dataframe by string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, filter

I have a pandas dataframe that I'd like to filter by a specific word (test) in a column. I tried:

`df[df[col].str.contains('test')]`

But it returns an empty dataframe with just the column names. For the output, I'm looking for a dataframe that'd contain all rows that contain the word 'test'. What can I do?

EDIT (to add samples):

`data = pd.read_csv(/...csv)`

data has 5 cols, including `'BusinessDescription'`, and I want to extract all rows that have the word 'dental' (case insensitive) in the `Business Description` col, so I used:

`filtered = data[data['BusinessDescription'].str.contains('dental')==True]`

and I get an empty dataframe, with just the header names of the 5 cols.

Comment: Can you add some data sample? Because it should working nice.

Comment: I just edited the original post to include more detail!

Comment: For future programming I'd recommend using the keyword `df` instead of `data` when refering to dataframes. It is the common way around SO to use that notation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you need parameter `flags` in [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
import re

filtered = data[data['BusinessDescription'].str.contains('dental', flags = re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Another solution, thanks  [Anton vBR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7386332/anton-vbr) is convert to lowercase first:

```
filtered = data[data['BusinessDescription'].str.lower().str.contains('dental')]
```

---

**Example:**
*For future programming I'd recommend using the keyword df instead of data when refering to dataframes. It is the common way around SO to use that notation.*

```
import pandas as pd

data = dict(BusinessDescription=['dental fluss','DENTAL','Dentist'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df['BusinessDescription'].str.lower().str.contains('dental')]

  BusinessDescription
0        dental fluss
1              DENTAL
```

**Timings**:

```
d = dict(BusinessDescription=['dental fluss','DENTAL','Dentist'])
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
data = pd.concat([data]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

#print (data)

In [122]: %timeit data[data['BusinessDescription'].str.contains('dental', flags = re.IGNORECASE)]
10 loops, best of 3: 28.9 ms per loop

In [123]: %timeit data[data['BusinessDescription'].str.lower().str.contains('dental')]
10 loops, best of 3: 32.6 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**:

Performance really depend on the data - size of `DataFrame` and number of values matching condition.

Comment: if case is the issue we could add `.lower()` after `str.` right? No need for module?

Comment: yes, I had done the ```import re``` before, but the ignorecase flag worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I do it with timings but you was faster ;)

Answer (score 6):

Keep the string enclosed in quotes.

```
df[df['col'].str.contains('test')]
```

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

It works also OK if you add a condition

```
df[df['col'].str.contains('test') == True]
```

Comment: yes i tried this as well, but still returns an empty dataframe with col headings... i wonder if it has something to do with the data type?

Comment: Downvotes because conditions in Python are evaluated against == True already making this redundant.