# Python: Why is .str.contains() only returning results for 4 out of 26 row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to print all of the rows that have the word tree in the first column(column A).

```
url = "https:www.example.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("txtBusinessName")
inputElement.send_keys("tree")

inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "grid_businessList"))
    )
finally:
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find('table', id="grid_businessList")
    rows = table.findAll("tr")

    columns = [v.text.replace('\xa0',' ') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for i in range(1, len(rows)):
        tds = rows[i].find_all('td')

        if len(tds) == 5:
            values = [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text, tds[5].text]
        else:
            values = [td.text for td in tds]


            df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

            biz = df[df['Business Name'].str.contains('tree')]

            print(biz)
```

But it only finds 'tree' in 4 of the rows even though its present in more.

It prints this 11 times:

Empty DataFrame

Columns: [A, B, C, D, E, F]

Index: []

Then it prints accurate results for lines 11, 13, 17, 20.

Why is .str.contains not looking in column A on each row?

Comment: The `try`-`finally` blocks are... kinda redundant without an `except` block in between.

Comment: Without any sample data to test against, it's very difficult to know what's going wrong. Please look at how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here: [how to filter pandas dataframe by string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020296/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-by-string). I just needed to flag in contains to re.IGNORECASE.